# tor running but can't connect through socks proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, socks

I have installed tor on Ubuntu 16.04. It seems to be running

```
$> ps aux |grep to
debian-+  1300  0.0  0.2  89504 44416 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:12 /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0
```

But if I try to tell Firefox to connect to a socks5 proxy via localhost:9150, when I navigate to any page, I get

```
 Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.
```

(NOTE: please don't advise me to use a "browser bundle", I want to configure other programs to use tor, Firefox is just a proof-of-life test case.)

Checking the port

```
$> sudo ss -l | grep tor -w
u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /var/run/tor/socks 27033                 * 0                    
u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /var/run/tor/control 27034                 * 0
```

Looks like tor is listening on a different port, but if I configure Firefox to use 27033 instead of 9150, I get the same error message.

The file `/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc` contains

```
SocksPort 9050
```

Using this port in Firefox configuration also doesn't work. The file `/etc/tor/torrc` contains nothing but comments.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure the connection is totally okay? You have to see `Bootstrapped 100%: Done.` in the log file. Use the command below to ensure that. tail -f /var/log/tor/log And there is an alternative to use apps through tor. Use the command `torify`. ----------------
**Edit** The problem here is the port your using. Tor uses `9050` as default port.

Comment: I [see that in the log](https://pastebin.com/kMJuQs9S), yes.

Comment: What about `torify`? Dose it works?

Comment: No, still no network access.

Comment: There's a problem with the port I think. Tor is always working on `9050` not `9150`

Comment: 9050 doesn't work either, as I said in the original question.

Comment: Tor socks port by default binds to loopback device only. Have you specified your socks server address as 127.0.0.1? This also means that it is only reachable from the machine tor is running on, if you want it to be accessible over a network you have to explicitly specify address to bind to.